# Poincaré inequality substracting the mean of the function over a smaller subset

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u:B \to \mathbb R$ be a $C^1$ function on the unit ball $B$.
Then, the classical Poincar'e inequality asserts that there exists $C>0$ such that
$$ \int_{B} |u - u_B|\, dx \leq C \int_{B} |\nabla u|\, dx $$
where $u_B = \frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B u\, dx$ is the mean of $u$ over $B$.

My question is can we substitute the mean $u_B$ by other quantities?
For example, does the inequality hold (with larger constant) with $u_{B_{1/2}} = \frac 1 {m(B_{1/2})} \int_{B_{1/2}} u \, dx$ (the mean of $u$ over half the unit ball)?

To clarify,
is the inequality
$$ \int_{B} |u - u_{B_{1/2}}\mid\, dx \leq C \int_{B} |\nabla u|\, dx $$
true for some $C>0$ and all $f \in C^1(B_1)$?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking if the Poincare inequality holds in $B_{1/2}$ or if it holds in $B_1$ except with $u_B$ replaced with $u_{B_{1/2}}$?

Comment: @JackT I want to know if it holds in $B_1$ but with the quantity $u_{B_{1/2}}$ instead of $u_{B_1}$.

Comment: I want to clarify that I'm also interested in whether there are other variations too. Maybe we could subtract the median of $u$ instead of the mean or other quantities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is easy to see if you do the usual proof by contradiction. What you really need is an assumption such that together with $\nabla u = 0$ a.e., it implies $u=0$.

If you look in *Analysis* by Lieb and Loss, Theorem 8.11, then you'll see a general version with $\int u g$ instead of $u_{B}$, and it is clear from the proof that you could choose $g$ the indicator of a given set of strictly positive measure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the reference was very helpful!